# No access to the Gallery nor to the camera

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, camera, gallery

I've got a Galaxy Nexus and recently I cannot access my gallery or camera. When I tap both on the Gallery icon or on the camera icon I got this message "No archives available", then the app shuts down. The only way to overcome as far as now is to completely reboot the phone. Phone is not rooted.

Comment: Are you running the latest Android version, 4.2.2?

Comment: Yes, it's a GSM model (I'm in Europe), running 4.2.2, no root or anything

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the Gallery cache.

1. Go into Settings->Apps and scroll over to show 'ALL' apps.
2. Scroll down and open 'Gallery'
3. If the 'Clear Cache' button is greyed-out, then you'll have to 'Force stop' the app first, then go ahead and clear the cache.

Exit out and try to open your Gallery again.